# Moving a Transporter Vertically (Z Axis) and Horizontally at the Same Time

Tags: java, anylogic

I've built a model for a storage facility using the material handling library. It is essentially a facility where users can store their belongings underground and have the system automatically store them into a shelving rack(s) and be able to retrieve them as needed where the associated belonging would be brought to a "pick up" room, also automatically. The transporter should be able to move in the Z-axis (vertically) at the same time as horizontally in a plane.

When using transporters in a model built from the material library, is there a way to make the transporter do that? The overhead crane is ideal for this purpose, but it doesn't count as a transporter so it doesn't seem like the Retrieve and Store blocks work with it. Is there a way to have the crane store and retrieve from a StorageSystem?

[image: Network]

Currently, the network is situated at the plane corresponding to the top of the rack.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. But you can always model around it: Destroy/hide/park a transporter agent on the upper level, put in a delay for moving vertically and recreate/reactivate the equivalent on the bottom level. There are a million different ways to do this, check some example models on how to do similar "creative" things :)